# CORS exception while accessing rest service from angular js using node.js server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, spring-mvc

I am using node.js server to consume rest resource from angular js application.

My angular application is running on port 8082 and rest resource available at port 9081. I am able to access rest resource but get CORS exception in developer console.

I find out the solution to get rid of CORS exception. I have used jsonp instead of get method in angular service also got response without any exception, but unable to perform operation on the data return with response.

I come to know that I have to use http-proxy to communicate cross domain applications. If it is right can you please suggest me how can I configure http-proxy in node.js server.

Comment: Did you configure cors settings on spring-mvc side?

Comment: Try adding middle ware code to allow access.                                    `app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type");
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST","PUT");
      next();
    });`

Comment: @Anil Kumar You can use the package [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)  Its a middleware which can be used to enable the cors with various options.

Comment: Thanks All.

I have tried above suggestions (using cors in node.js and set header to all response) but failed.

I can access the rest service and can see the success response in network tab, but getting the same error in console. 

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9082/testing/getAllProfiles. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8082' is therefore not allowed access.

@IIker Can I get any reference link to set up cors setting on spring-mvc side.